# build runner is not found in VS Studio

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, code-generation, flutter-dependencies

I was following Resocoders super enum tutorial, and I got stuck when he did a build runner command to generate a new dart file. Even though I had the same libraries as him and followed the tutorial to the up to that point, VS Studio could not detect the build task. How do I get it to detect build_runner and generate the file?

```
name: super_enum_tutorial
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
 sdk: flutter
super_enum: ^0.2.0
flutter_bloc: ^2.1.1
equatable: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
 sdk: flutter
build_runner:
super_enum_generator: ^0.2.0



flutter:

uses-material-design: true
```

[image: build task not detected]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the of in line 5 of your code, like this part 'weather_state.g.dart', then save the file then run flutter pub run build_runner build.